# Gradle dependency resolution issue

Tags: gradle

I am converting a project from `Maven` to `Gradle`.

Here is my `gradle.build` file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.5.30"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring" version "1.5.30"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.5.4"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

group = 'com.aeonai.lib'
version = '1.0.0'
description = 'Aeon AI Library'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = uri 'https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/'
    }
    maven {
        url = uri 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-cql:25.2:sources@jar'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:25.2:sources@jar'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-geojson:25.2:sources@jar'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-main:25.2:sources@jar'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-opengis:25.2:sources@jar'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-shapefile:25.2:sources@jar'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    ...
}

configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
}

bootRun.enabled = false

bootJar {
    mainClass.set('NONE')
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am importing many of the `geotools` from `https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/`.

When I run `gradle build` all of my dependency show up as they should, but the build still fails. The compiler cannot find some of the dependencies (which I have added in a screenshot below), although I can see the files in the `External Libraries` tree (also in a screenshot below). I can also see the libraries in the `~/.gradle/caches`.

Here is a screenshot of the files not being found.

[image]

Here is another screenshot of the files in the tree.

[image]

Why is gradle/compiler not recognizing the file is there? What else am I missing?

Comment: You'll need to provide details of how your project is structured and the Gradle file contents.

Comment: if your gradle build is running fine, the issue is with the IDE rather than gradle. if you have not already done - remove the poms and reimport the project as gradle project

Comment: The gradle build does not finish. It fails when building the jar, because it cannot find the dependencies above. It just downloads the proper dependencies, which I verified by looking in the gradle cache and finding them.